# Div failing to have any effect on the contents

Tags: html, css

I am currently designing a new server-client interface for a gameserver, and have stumbled across a problem, that one of my `div` classes does not have any affect on the contents.

The [site is live (http://crysis-or.eu/)](http://crysis-or.eu/), and the HTML/PHP & CSS can be viewed.

The specific contents which the `<div class="tableenc">` is attempting to have an effect on is the table; I am attempting to move the table to the left, but however the table is not moving.

I have tried a few things, such as moving `<div class="tableenc">` outside of `<body>` (and obviously modifying the relevant part of the CSS), but nothing has worked.

What am I doing wrong?

Problem code:

PHP/HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="tableenc">
            <table class="login" width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
                <tr>
                    <form name="form1" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
                        <td>
                            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="3"><strong><font color="#265CFF"><h2>Login to Crysis Wars Server Portal</h2></font></strong></td>
                                    </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="78"><font color="#265CFF">Username</font></td>
                                    <td width="6"><font color="#265CFF">:</font></td>
                                    <td width="294"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><font color="#265CFF">Password</font></td>
                                    <td><font color="#265CFF">:</font></td>
                                    <td><input name="mypassword" type="text" id="mypassword"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </form>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    width:100%;
    margin-left:-0px;
    background:url("../img/pgbg.jpg") repeat-x;
}
body > table {
    position:absolute;
}

body > .tableenc {
    margin-right:70px;
}
```

Comment: Your HTML is outright invalid. You cannot put a `<form>` where you are. And the 1990's called and want its `<font>` tags back

Comment: What does PHP have to do with this?

Comment: @MarcB It's still under development, I need to get the initial style first, then I will refine it.

Comment: no excuse for writing bad html. you'll spend more trying to convince the browser to **NOT** fix your bad html than it'd take you just write proper html to start with.

Comment: Form ALWAYS follows function... I don't think any user cares how it looks.. if it's broken it's broken. Rework the markup and worry about style later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a lot of work for a simple form. You could start from a simpler foundation and see if that helps you move it around.

[Have a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/tN2uB/)

HTML

```
<form id="login" name="form1" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
    <legend>Login to Crysis Wars Server Portal</legend>
    <label for="myusername">Username</label>
    <input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername" />
    <label for="mypassword">Password</label>
    <input name="mypassword" type="text" id="mypassword" />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

CSS

```
#login {
    width: 300px;
}
#login legend {
    color: #265CFF;
    font-size: 2em;
}
#login input {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px 0 0;
}
#login label {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    clear: left;
    margin: 20px 0 0;
}
#login input[type=submit] {
    clear: left;
}
```

Comment: I tried this after fixing the issues with the HTML, and it worked perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML markup is not valid for any version of HTML. You can't place a form tag in the middle of the table markup like that. Your browser is likely being tolerant of the mistake and adapting the markup as best it can. This is most likely why your display settings are not having the intended effect. I would point you toward the [W3 Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) as a means to check your code for conformity so you can avoid this issue in the future. If you fix the markup, those styles may begin to work the way you expected.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll fix the errors, and see if the desired code works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, creating a container div that implements the use of form, label, and input tags would be much more practical.